# Spark ml streaming predictOnValues how to save results?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-ml

I have following code:

```
StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD regressionWithSGD =
        new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
                .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(featuresNumber));

JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> trainingData = streamingContext.textFileStream(model.getTrainPath()).map(LabeledPoint::parse).cache();
JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> testData = streamingContext.textFileStream(model.getPredictPath()).map(LabeledPoint::parse);
regressionWithSGD.trainOn(trainingData);
regressionWithSGD.predictOnValues(testData.mapToPair(lp -> new Tuple2<>(lp.label(), lp.features()))).print();
```

I would like to put results to some file/db/queue and so on instead of `print()` is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out

```
StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD regressionWithSGD =
                new StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD()
                        .setInitialWeights(Vectors.zeros(featuresNumber));

        JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> trainingData = streamingContext.textFileStream(model.getTrainPath()).map(LabeledPoint::parse).cache();
        JavaDStream<LabeledPoint> testData = streamingContext.textFileStream(model.getPredictPath()).map(LabeledPoint::parse);
        regressionWithSGD.trainOn(trainingData);
        JavaDStream<Double> doubleJavaDStream=regressionWithSGD.predictOn(testData.map(labeledPoint -> labeledPoint.features()));
        doubleJavaDStream.dstream().saveAsTextFiles("result","out");
```

So as a result we are getting result-{timestamp}.out folders.